# Understanding the output of my Ramsey RESET test

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I am new to R, and doing a replication study where I need to check if their regression holds for the classical assumption for OLS. For the specification assumption, I am doing the Ramsey RESET test, here is my code:

```
simple_model <- lm(deploy ~ loggdppc + natoyears + milspend + lagdeploy + logland + logcoast + lag3terror + logmindist)

resettest(simple_model, power=2, type="regressor", data = natopanel)
```

Here is my output:

```
RESET = 2.0719, df1 = 6, df2 = 355, p-value = 0.05586
```

Since the P-value is (albeit slightly) above 0.05, does this mean that it 'passes' the RAMSEY test? Or is there an issue of missing variables? I still have not gotten quite the hang of these interpretations. This model does not include all their variables, as they are testing for a specific hypothesis.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/376385

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_RESET_test):

> *"[The intuition of Ramsey RESET] test is that if non-linear combinations of the explanatory variables have any power in explaining the response
> variable, the model is misspecified in the sense that the data
> generating process might be better approximated by a polynomial or
> another non-linear functional form"*

It tests whether including higher degree polynomials of your explanatory variables -- in your example 2nd degree due to `power=2` -- have any additional explanatory power. In essence, you test whether the 2nd-degree terms of your regressors are jointly significantly different from zero.

Suppose you use 5% as your cut-off for significance. In that case, you (barely) fail to reject the null hypothesis that including the 2nd-degree terms improves the fit over a linear model.

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to statistics in general, so I am still trying to get a hang of it, as it is not very 'intuitive' for me yet. Do you happen to know the difference between the 'types' in the code (fitted, regressor, and princomp)? Or, I know what they stand for, but when are the different ones appropriate? Since I am doing a regression model, I assumed 'regressor' would be the correct one, but I see they all yield very different results.

Comment: `princomp`  refers to the first principal component of the regressor matrix. Principal components are a way to compress correlated regressors into a single variable. `fitted` refers to fitted values of the original regression model (`simple_model` in your question). Essentially, this is another way to combine multiple X'es into a single explanatory variable, which is based on the correlation between the dependent variable and regressors.

Comment: Thank you, again. I ended up choosing the fitted model, and the result changed to 'RESET = 0.90699, df1 = 2, df2 = 357, p-value = 0.4047', which seems a little more promising for the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would review your response that using 'fitted' gives you a p-value of 0.4047.

Remember that the purpose of this test is to see if in your model we should use quadratic or higher power terms.  The null hypothesis is that quadratic (or higher power) is better.  If we reject the null in this case then we are saying that statistically first order terms are better.

When you get a p-value of less than 0.05 this means that you reject the null hypothesis - this means that statistically your model is better with first order terms.  When you got 0.05568 you should've investigated further if you needed more than first order terms in your model.

When you added in 'fitted' etc the p value was even higher.  This means that there is even less certainty that first order terms are sufficient.

It is REALLY important to know what you are doing with the values "fitted", "regressor" and "principal".